# F#: Grouping a complex list

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am trying to group the list by each element of player list

```
let playersScore= [ 
  (["Player 1";"Player 2";], "First Game");
  (["Player 2";"Player 3";"Player 4";], "Second Game");
  (["Player 3"], "Third Game");
  (["Player 1";"Player 2";"Player 3";"Player 4";], "Last Game")] : scorePlayerItem list
```

What I want to get is to find which player has joined to which games as

```
(string * string list) list
```

For example according to that list

1. Player1 -> First Game, Last Game
2. Player2 -> First Game, Second Game
3. Player3 -> Second, Third Game, Last Game
4. Player4 -> Second Game, Last Game

I tried to use `List.groupBy` but could not achive this. I just could not manage to group items by each element of player list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple solution:

```
let groups =
    playersScore
    |> List.collect (fun (players, game) -> players |> List.map (fun player -> player, game))
    |> List.groupBy (fun (player, _) -> player)
    |> Map.ofList
    |> Map.map (fun _ games -> games |> List.map snd)
```

Break out the list of lists into a flat structure, group them by player, then convert to a map with the player as the key, and finally map the values to get just the name of the game.  This produces the following map:

```
map
  [("Player 1", ["First Game"; "Last Game"]);
   ("Player 2", ["First Game"; "Second Game"; "Last Game"]);
   ("Player 3", ["Second Game"; "Third Game"; "Last Game"]);
   ("Player 4", ["Second Game"; "Last Game"])]
```

**EDIT**

To keep things as a list, you can just use `List.map` instead of `Map.ofList` and `Map.map`:

```
let groups =
    playersScore
    |> List.collect (fun (players, game) -> players |> List.map (fun player -> player, game))
    |> List.groupBy (fun (player, _) -> player)
    |> List.map (fun (player, games) -> player, games |> List.map snd)
```

This returns the equivalent result as a list:

```
[("Player 1", ["First Game"; "Last Game"]);
 ("Player 2", ["First Game"; "Second Game"; "Last Game"]);
 ("Player 3", ["Second Game"; "Third Game"; "Last Game"]);
 ("Player 4", ["Second Game"; "Last Game"])]
```

Comment: is it possible to return (string * string list) list instead of map ?

Comment: @Tartar Updated the answer to include a solution that uses only lists.

Comment: What does snd stand for ?

Comment: @Tartar `snd` is the built-in function for extracting the second element in a tuple.  If you call `snd ('a', 'b')`, you'll get 'b'.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.